# Angular code is not displaying all orders

Tags: angularjs

```
/*------Factory method---------*/
factory.getAllOrders = function() {
       var orders = [];
       for(var i=0, len=customers.length; i<len; i++){
           if(customers[i].orders) {
               for(var j=0,ordersLen=customers[i].orders.length; j<ordersLen; j++){
                   return customers[i].orders;
               }
           }

       }

   };
  return factory;


/*-----------All orders controller--------------*/


myApp.controller('AllOrdersController',['$scope','$routeParams','customersFactory', function($scope,$routeParams,customersFactory) {
   $scope.orders = null;
   $scope.ordersTotal = 0.0;
   $scope.totalType;

   function init() {
       $scope.orders = customersFactory.getAllOrders();
   }

   function getOrdersTotal(){
       var total = 0;
       for(var i=0,len=$scope.orders.length; i<len; i++) {
           total += $scope.orders[i].total;
       }
       $scope.ordersTotal = total;
       $scope.totalType = ($scope.ordersTotal > 100) ? 'success' :'danger';
   }

   init();



]);

   <!-- View -->
   <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4">
           <h2>Customers Orders</h2>
br/>
           Filte:<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="orderFilter.product" />
           <br/>
           <br/>
       </div>
   </div>
/div>


div class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
           <table class="table table-responsive">
                <tr>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="order in orders | filter:orderFilter | orderBy:'name'">
                    <td>{{order.product}}</td>
                    <td>{{order.total | currency}}</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>{{ordersTotal | currency}}</td>
                 </tr>
           </table>
       </div>
   </div>
/div>

/*--------------JSON FIle-----------------*/
var customers = [
        id: "1",
        joined: "2000-12-2",
        name: "Wali",
        city: "Dubai",
        orderTotal: "9.0765",
        orders: [{
            id: "1",
            product: "protein",
            total: "11.987"
        }]
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        joined: "2004-12-2",
        name: "Ali",
        city: "London",
        orderTotal: "20.0765",
        orders: [{
            id: "2",
            product: "bcca",
            total: "2.3456"
        }, {
            id: "3",
            product: "baseball",
            total: "4.3456"
        }]
    }];
```

I have make a controllers which display all orders from json file and I have given a functionality of all orders via factory method. I want to print table that parse data from json file and gives all the orders of the customer, but it is displaying orders for the first customer only and I want to display all orders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the data prematurely. The line

```
return customers[i].orders;
```

will return control back to the controller after only the first pass of the inner and outer loop in the factory (i=0, j=0), which is why you are getting only the first customer's orders. Instead, if you want all the customers' orders you should loop through the customers and push their corresponding orders into the order array you have declared. This is the code for that:

```
factory.getAllOrders = function() {
    var orders = [];
    for(var i=0, len=customers.length; i<len; i++){
        if (customers[i].orders) {
            ordersLen=customers[i].orders.length;
            for (var j=0; j<ordersLen; j++){
                orders.push(customers[i].orders[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return orders;
};
return factory;
```

However, this will return an array of objects and ng-repeater will think there are duplicates because on the surface they are all Object. In such a situation, it is recommended to use the **track by** option. The following is the modified ng-repeater code:

```
<table class="table table-responsive">
    <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="order in orders | filter:orderFilter | orderBy:'name' track by $index">
        <td>@{{order.product}}</td>
        <td>@{{order.total | currency}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>@{{ordersTotal | currency}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This error is showing in the consoleError: [ngRepeat:dupes] errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/ngRepeat/……223%‌​22%2C%22product%22%3A%22baseball%22%2C%22total%22%3A%224.3456%22%7D%5D at Error (native)

Comment: A couple of things (breaking it into two comments) :

The orders array returned from the factory consists of a series of objects and on the surface they all look the same (Object). That is why ng-repeater thinks there are duplicates. In such a situation, you can use the track by option to run through the array by using some unique index (either the array's or from within the object)

Comment: Secondly, I made a mistake. I had been pushing the entire orders array corresponding to a customer into the orders array variable in the factory, thus creating an array of arrays, which is why even with the track by option nothing would be displayed since ng-repeater was not going deep enough. So, I am editing my answer to reflect the same. It should work now.

Comment: Thanks for solving

Answer (score 1):

```
factory.getAllOrders = function() {
    var orders = [];
    for(var i=0, len=customers.length; i<len; i++){
        if (customers[i].orders) {
            for (var j=0,ordersLen=customers[i].orders.length; j<ordersLen; j++){
                orders.push(customers[i].orders);
            }
        }
    }
    return orders;
};
return factory;
```

Comment: This error is showing in the consoleError: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=order%20in%20orders%20%…223%22%2C%22product%22%3A%22baseball%22%2C%22total%22%3A%224.3456%22%7D%5D
    at Error (native)

Comment: use track by $index in ng-repeat

Comment: That/s if you want to have duplicates, otherwise you'd have to check if order already exists befour pushing it into array